# DC dynamic bar chart X-axis

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to create a dynamic bar chart. Space between the bars is not getting changed. Here is the code and snapshots. Plz help me solving it. Thanks in advance.

```
chart
                .width(1000)
                .height(480)
                .brushOn(false)
                .elasticX(true)
                .yAxisLabel("This is the Y Axis!")
                .barPadding(0.5)
```

Here is my X axis onchange code. I have added a drop down for it.

```
$("#x").on("change", function(){
                xaxis = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck($(this).val()));
                chart.dimension(xaxis)
                .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
                .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
                if(yaxis!= null)
                {
                    yaxis =  xaxis.group().reduceCount(dc.pluck($("#y").val()));
                    chart.group(yaxis);
                    chart.elasticY(true);
                    chart.effectiveWidth();
                    chart.render();
                }
            });
```

[image][image]